# How to do pivot in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data like this

```
Col_A     Col_B      Col_C    Value    Col_E
Id_1    String_a   type1      null     Flat
Id_1    String_a   type2      30       Not Flat
Id_1    String_b   type1      null     Flat
Id_1    String_b   type2      30       Not Flat
Id_2    String_c   type1      35       Flat
Id_2    String_c   type2      55       Flat
```

I want the output to be like below

```
Col_A    type1_Col_E  type1  type1_count type2_Col_E  type_2 type2_count
Id_1     Flat         null   0           Not Flat     30     2
Id_2     Flat         35     1           Flat         35     1
```

I need to have all the types as column and need counts as another column for each of its type. So if I have 2 strings associated to one Id, I should have the count as 2 in its type. I need to have all the types as column and I need to have the count to indicate how many strings got associated to each of the type. If the Value is null, I should consider the count as zero.

Is it possible to achieve this with PL SQL?

Comment: Are you trying to indicate that the number of columns (and the column headings) is variable? if not, the number of columns is fixed, sql will be sufficient.

Comment: What if for Id_1, the col_e was different for type1 for string_a and string_b? What should the output be in that case?

Comment: Those data will be same in that case @Boneist.  Because Col_A, Col_C, Col_D and Col_E are coming from one table. So those values would be same for each Id

Answer (score 0):

*You don't need `PL/SQL`, but `SQL Select` statement with correlated subqueries as below best suits for your case as below :*

```
with tab( Col_A, Col_B, Col_C, Value, Col_E ) as
(
 select 'Id_1','String_a','type1',null,'Flat'     from dual union all
 select 'Id_1','String_a','type2',  30,'Not Flat' from dual union all
 select 'Id_1','String_b','type1',null,'Flat'     from dual union all
 select 'Id_1','String_b','type2',  30,'Not Flat' from dual union all
 select 'Id_2','String_c','type1',  35,'Flat'     from dual union all
 select 'Id_2','String_c','type2',  55,'Flat'     from dual 
)
select Col_A,
       ( select distinct Col_E from tab where Col_A = t.Col_A and Col_C = 'type1' ) 
         as type1_Col_E,
       ( select distinct value from tab where Col_A = t.Col_A and Col_C = 'type1' )   
         as type1,
       ( select sum(nvl2(value,1,0)) from tab where Col_A = t.Col_A and Col_C = 'type1' )   
         as type1_count,
       ( select distinct Col_E from tab where Col_A = t.Col_A and Col_C = 'type2' ) 
         as type2_Col_E,
       ( select distinct value from tab where Col_A = t.Col_A and Col_C = 'type2' )   
         as type2,
       ( select sum(nvl2(value,1,0)) from tab where Col_A = t.Col_A and Col_C = 'type2' )   
         as type2_count                        
      from tab t
     group by t.Col_A;

COL_A   TYPE1_COL_E  TYPE1  TYPE1_COUNT TYPE2_COL_E  TYPE2  TYPE2_COUNT
-----  -----------  ------- ----------- -----------  ------ -----------
Id_1     Flat         null      0        Not Flat      30        2
Id_2     Flat         35        1        Flat          35        1
```